# AHB AP transaction error with zynq board

Tags: xilinx, vivado, adc, zynq, jtag

I'm new at zynq board. I am trying to work with XADC of zynq-xc7z020 and want to see its quality for my application through vivado and xilinx SDK.

I tested two ways of designing through [lab3](http://zynqhowto.blogspot.kr/2014/03/zynq-how-tolab3.html) and [lab4](http://zynqhowto.blogspot.kr/2014/04/zynq-how-to-lab4.html) tutorials. Synthesis, implementation and generating bitstream are OK in vivado. in the Xilinx SDK, after programming of the board, when I run a simple `printf` through system debugger or GDB but I get "AHB AP transaction Error". I googled it a lot and spent few days for it, but didn't get any solution. Additional, I tried to connect to the arm core of the board through XMD console by "connect arm hw" command. but console get JTAG connection error, while JTAG cable is connected and programming of the board is done.

suggested solutions of [here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/AP-transaction-Error/td-p/369465) didn't help.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what my mistake was.

Through XSCT console in SDK, I run `mrd` command to access DDR and read its address. but I couldn't. So I got that the problem was from DDR configurations.

I create a new project and at the first step of designing, after adding ZYNQ7 Processing System to block design, click on 'run block automation' and continue all previous steps and it worked. The point was that automation run. It sets some auto configuration of block that have to be set; and my mistake was this, that I connected DDR port manually.